# Sonar "useless assignment to local variable" workaround?

Tags: java, null, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am working towards improving my code, and I came across this issue from Sonar:

```
Remove this useless assignment to local variable "uiRequest"
```

Fact is, it is not useless, as I am using it just after in the code:

```
        // I am supposed to remove this
        UiRequest uiRequest = null;

        if("Party".equals(vauban.getName()))   {
            uiRequest = contextBuilder.buildContext(vauban);
        } else {
            // Maybe I could work my way around here ?
            throw new NamingException(
                    String.format(
                            "Hey %s, change your name to %s, thanks",
                            vauban.getName(), "Vauban"));
        }

        // Set the generated Id in the result of context builder
        MyOwnService response = callService(uiRequest, vauban);

        return response;
```

Sonar still tells me that "uiRequest" is useless, why ? It is not, as I don't want it to reach the code if it is null. I tried initializing it (`uiRequest = new UiRequest()`) but it keeps telling me that it is useless.

Anyone got an idea about why Sonar behaves like this / how to correct this ?

Comment: It is absolutely useless because the block of code that uses it `callService(uiRequest, vauban)` would never be reached if uiRequest were using the assignment to null.

Comment: not `uiRequest`is useless, but assigning `null`to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue simplifies to:

```
Foo x = null;

if(a()) {
     x = b();
} else {
     throw new Exception();
}

c(x);
```

There are two potential paths through this code:

1. `a()` returns `true`. `x` is assigned `b()` then `c(x)` is called.
2. `a()` returns `false`. An exception is thrown and `c(x)` is not called.

Neither of these paths calls `c(x)` using the initial assignment of `null`. So whatever you assigned at first, is redundant.

Note that this would also be an issue if the initial assignment was something other than null. Unless the right-hand-side of the assignment has a *side effect*, any assignment is wasted. (Sonar analyses for side-effects)

This is suspicious to Sonar:

- Maybe the programmer expected the first assignment to have an effect -- it doesn't, so perhaps it's a bug.
- It's also about code clarity -- a future human reader of the code might waste time wondering what the initial value is for.
- If the right-hand-side had involved computation, but had no side effect, it would be wasted computation.

You can fix this in two ways:

Firstly just removing the `= null`, leaving `Foo x;` - Java is clever enough to realise that all routes to `c(x)` involve an assignment, so this will still compile.

Better yet, move `c(x)` into the block:

```
if(a()) {
     Foo x = b();
     c(x);
} else {
     throw new Exception();
}
```

This is logically equivalent, neater, and reduces the scope of `x`. Reducing scope is a good thing. Of course, if you *need* `x` in the wider scope, you can't do this.

One more variation, also logically equivalent:

```
if(! a()) {
   throw new Exception();
}

Foo x = b();
c(x);
```

... which responds well to "extract-method" and "inline" refactorings:

```
throwForInvalidA(...);
c(b());
```

Use whichever communicates your intent best.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the warning and perhaps have slightly more readable code by:

```
// I am supposed to remove this
//    UiRequest uiRequest = null;  <-- remove

// invert the test here
    if(! "Party".equals(vauban.getName()))   {
        // Maybe I could work my way around here ?
        throw new NamingException(
                String.format(
                        "Hey %s, change your name to %s, thanks",
                        vauban.getName(), "Vauban"));
    } 

    // you are only using the variable in the call service; make
    //   final since reference should not change after assignment
    final UiRequest uiRequest = contextBuilder.buildContext(vauban);

    // Set the generated Id in the result of context builder
    MyOwnService response = callService(uiRequest, vauban);

    return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about moving it into the if statement?

```
    if("Party".equals(vauban.getName()))   {
        UiRequest uiRequest = contextBuilder.buildContext(vauban);
        // Set the generated Id in the result of context builder
        MyOwnService response = callService(uiRequest, vauban);
        return response;
    } else {
        throw new NamingException(
                String.format(
                        "Hey %s, change your name to %s, thanks",
                        vauban.getName(), "Vauban"));
    }
```

Or throw exception in the if statement and just have no else clause. i.e let the normal case be the "happy path".

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is useless because no code can possibly see that assigned value.